# How to set up the regular expression to find the variables with grep or matches of dplyr in R?

Tags: regex, r, dplyr, grepl

For example, there are variable name list like

```
variable<- c('A1234','A1234M6','A1234X5','A1565','A2456Z4','1245')
```

Here I want to set up the regular expressions to find the variable names which are started by A and with only numbers avilable after the A? ie., return `'A1234'` and `'A1565'` only, I tried the following code,

```
var[grepl('^A[0-9]',var)]
```

It will return all the variables start by A, how I can revise the code to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We match the pattern in string that starts (`^`) with 'A' followed by one or more numbers (`[0-9]+`) to the end of the string (`$`).

```
grep('^A[0-9]+$', variable, value=TRUE)
```

If the rule is based on the length, say 4, we can specify that in curly brackets to limit the strings that have number of characters 5 and matching 'A' as the first character followed by 4 numbers to the end of the string.

```
grep('^A[0-9]{4}$', variable, value=TRUE)
```

Comment: Great,thanks. What if I want try to select it according to the rule of length, say it's a length of 4 after A?

Comment: @johnsonzhj  Updated the post.  I am guessing that you want to select only strings of length 5 and also that match the first character as A and the next four as numbers?

Comment: yes,exactly,cool answer and nice explanation! Can you also slightly update the answer to explain why add "+" there for the first half of the answer?